# Send Context and URI Using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send context and uri to other class using intent. This the code that I will use.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, builder.build(), context, Start.class);
```

I hesitate in `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` because I think it's use to call the browser. But, I just want to send context and uri to Start.class. Should I set string action parameter to null? or maybe you have a good way to fix this case.

Comment: You cannot "send" a context.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a `Context` to another "class" via an `Intent`. Whatever is responding to this `Intent` is already a `Context`.

You can attach a `Uri` to an explicit `Intent`, though:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Something.class).setData(yourDesiredUri);
```

It is possible that your syntax, with a `null` first parameter, is equivalent to what I have above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just response your message now. I've used your code and it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send Context variable via Intent but You can access Context using static variables:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity{

    ...
    public static instance = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        instance = this;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        ...
        instance = null;
        ...
    }
}
```

To access instance You can use this:

```
FirstActivity.instance;
```

Don't forget to check NullPointerException :)